# Using the ProGuard in android studio

Tags: android

I know there are many contents about my question. But I really do not understand. Please see the following code. When I create a new project in android studio, my `Build.gradle` is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

Please do not give links to me and please say to me, what I should do in this file to use the **ProGuard**.

UPDATE, My Errors:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\tec\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Test'.
> Could not find method minifyEnabled() for arguments [true] on BuildTypeDsl_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, jniDebugBuild=false, renderscriptDebugBuild=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, packageNameSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=null, runProguard=false, zipAlign=true, signingConfig=null}.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

I edited my `Bild.gradle` as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    buildTypes {

        release

                { minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

                }

    }
}
```

My project is the same simple and default project in android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `android{ }`

Put this

```
buildTypes {

 release

 { minifyEnabled true 
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 

}

 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I do carefully and I get **Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.**

Comment: It is saying file not found

Comment: Try to replace `minifyEnabled` with `runProguard`

Comment: I'm leaving for future users how come here the `minifyEnabled` didn't  work because of older gradle when it updates it will work normally